# Use RxSwift to handle the keyboardWillHide

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I would like to enable a button when the keyboard is hidden. How can I do this using rxSwift? I tried this code but the closure is never called:

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
    .map { _ in if let cancelButton = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton {
    cancelButton.isEnabled = true
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Observables don't do anything unless they are subscribed to. Since you did not use a `subscribe` (or `bind` which is a `subscribe` that asserts if an error is observed) the Observer didn't do anything. It's kind of like creating an object but never calling any of its functions.

I would write it like this:

```
let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as! UIButton
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
    .map { _ in true }
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(cancelButton.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the .take(1) bit cause the subscription to be disposed after the first event? I.e. it looks like this will work fine for the first event only.

Comment: What does it matter? Once the stream emits a true it will never emit false anyway. If you are changing the button's `isEnabled` by some other means. I recommend you don't do that and instead expand this stream to include everything that affects the value.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is correct and probably the simplest way of doing it, but here is another example of doing the same thing using RxCocoa:

```
let keyboardShown = NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
let keyboardHidden = NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)

let isCancelEnabled = Observable.merge(keyboardShown.map { _ in false }, keyboardHidden.map { _ in true })
    .startWith(false)
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)

let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as! UIButton

isCancelEnabled
    .drive(cancelButton.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This might be a slightly longer version of doing it but it is now very simple to employ an MVVM pattern, with the isCancelEnabled being declared in the ViewModel and cancelButton 'driving' in the ViewController.

P.S. I don't think you want to include the .take(1) as suggested by Daniel as this will work fine for the first event but then the subscription will get disposed and it will no longer work.

Comment: This is a great answer if it is the case that the OP wants the button disabled when the keyboard is show and enabled when it is hidden. The OP didn't give us the conditions as to when the button should be disabled so it might not fit. I was just answering the exact question asked and not making any assumptions about what disables the button.